# List to tuple counting values repeated and the list inside the tuple - Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming, tuples

im learning functional programming with Haskell and i have this exercise where i have something like `[a], z`, with `[a]` any kind of list and `z` the element that im gonna erase inside `[a]`. This problem it's kinda easy to solve (even for a newbie like me in Haskell) but I am having troubles with the way I need to print the output.

I need to create a **tuple** where the first element is the list without any `z` element and the number of times that it found `z` inside of `a`. Couple examples:

- Input: `[2,3,4,2,2] 2`
- Output: `([3,4],3)`
- Input: `[1,1,1,1] 1`
- Output: `([],4)`
- Input: `[1,2,3,4] 5`
- Output: `([1,2,3,4],0)`

So far i've done something like this but I don't know how to keep going:

```
ex3 :: (Eq a, Num a) => [a] -> a -> ([a],Int)
ex3 [] _ = ([],0)
ex3 (x:xs) z | x == z = (xs,1) -- this line is wrong, but idk how to fix it
             | otherwise = ([0],0) -- same here
```

I've done both problems individually (deleting `z` elements and counting how many times `z` is in `[a]`. Looks like this:

a) Deleting `z` elements:

```
ex3a :: (Eq a) => [a] -> a -> [a]
ex3a [] _ = []
ex3a (x:xs) z | x == z = ex3a xs z
              | otherwise = x : ex3a xs z
```

b) Counting how many times `z` is in `[a]`:

```
ex3b :: (Eq a) => [a] -> a -> Int
ex3b [] _ = 0
ex3b (x:xs) z | x == z = 1 + ex3b xs z
              | otherwise = ex3b xs z
```

Comment: Perhaps you better first aim to solve it without counting. How would you implement such "erasure" function that only returns the list?

Comment: I already did what you're suggesting, but i'm now trying to "merge" both problems in a single one and i just can't.

Comment: is it possible to show an implementation? I think it will probably result in a better answer by showing how we can *alter* the previous function.

Comment: Of course, Willem. I've just added both implementations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually it helps to think of functions like in mathematics you think about *inductive definitions*. For example the first line of your function can read like:

"*The `ex3` of an empty list, and any element is a tuple containing the empty list and zero*"

```
ex3 [] _ = ([], 0)
```

For non-empty lists of course the problem is a bit harder. Like in your code, there are basically two cases here.

"*The `ex3` of a non-empty list and an element `z` where the head of the list is* not *equal to `z` is the same as the `ex3` of the* tail *of the list*, but prepended with the head of that list", so we can write it like:

```
ex3 [] _ = ([], 0)
ex3 (x:xs) z | x /= z = (x:t, n)
             | otherwise = ...
    where (t, n) = ex3 xs z
```

So here we make a recursive call to `ex3` with the tail of the list `xs`, and we obtain the result tuple `(t, n)`, so `t` contains the "erased" tail, and `n` the number of times we removed the element, and in case `x /= z`, then we can return `(x:t, n)`, since the number of removals does not change, but we have to prepend `x` to the list.

"*The `ex3` of a non-empty list and an element `z` where the head of the list is equal to `z` is the same as the `ex3` of the* tail *of the list but with an incremented count*", so:

```
ex3 :: (Eq a, Num n) => [a] -> a -> ([a], n)
ex3 [] _ = ([], 0)
ex3 (x:xs) z | x /= z = (x:t, n)
             | otherwise = (t, n+1)
    where (t, n) = ex3 xs z
```

We then obtain the expected results:

```
Prelude> ex3 [2,3,4,2,2] 2
([3,4],3)
Prelude> ex3 [1,1,1,1] 1
([],4)
Prelude> ex3 [1,2,3,4] 5
([1,2,3,4],0)
```

Comment: Excellent answer, very didactical and it totally helped me. I'm excited about learning more of this programming language, it's a very different approach if we compare with PL like C, Java, etc. Thank you, Willem. I probably will be around again to keep asking and learning from the best! Keep rockin, buddy!

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, this is how I would implement that function:

```
import Data.Foldable
import Data.Monoid

ex3 :: Eq a => [a] -> a -> ([a], Int)
ex3 haystack needle = getSum <$> foldMap inject haystack where
    inject hay | hay == needle = ([], 1)
               | otherwise     = ([hay], 0)
```

What I like about this is that the recursion pattern is immediately obvious -- at least to those familiar with Haskell's standard library -- without careful scrutiny (because it is just a call to `foldMap`).

Comment: You're slightly cheating with that `Sum Int` in your result type. :-) But very neat code.

Comment: @melpomene Okay. No cheating now.

Comment: Yeah, now you're using the `Functor` instance of `(,) a`, which is probably another hurdle for beginners. But you did say you were answering for fun and I would totally do the same thing, so there's nothing left to nitpick. Well played. :-)

Comment: 35% fewer tokens than the competition!

Comment: This answer requires you know the default Monoid for `(a, b)`, too (which caused me to go look that up, so now I know that woohoo! :D)

Answer (score 0):

The partition function consumes a predicate and a list; it produces a pair of lists whose first element satisfies the predicate, the second doesn't.

```
import Data.List (partition)

ex4 :: Eq a => [a] -> a -> ([a], Int)
ex4 xs x = length <$> partition (/= x) xs
```